# Creating dicts from file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, input

For example, I've got file with multilines like

```
<<something>>   1, 5, 8
<<somethingelse>> hello
<<somethingelseelse>> 1,5,6
```

I need to create dict with keys

```
dict = { "something":[1,5,8], "somethingelse": "hello" ...}
```

I need to somehow read what is inside << >> and put it as a key, and also I need to check if there are a lot of elements or only 1. If only one then I put it as string. If more then one then I need to put it as a list of elements.
Any ideas how to help me?
Maybe regEx's but I'm not great with them.

I easily created def which is reading a file lines, but don't know how to separate those values:

```
f = open('something.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

def finding_path():
    for line in lines:
        print line

finding_path()
f.close()
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: So by what rules is there more than one value? If there is a comma? Do you always have *integers* then (your expected output has converted the digits to `int` values).

Comment: there is no rules, but I can check if there are "," signs so im sure there will be more then 1 value. and if there is no "," it will be just a string, and they are not allways ints, they can be possible strings but we need to put them in a list instead of single string

Comment: You don't need to close the file twice. And why not pass in the filename into the function rather than use globals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your keys will always be single words, you can play with  [split(char, maxSplits)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Something like below

```
import sys

def finding_path(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    my_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        # split on first occurance of space
        key_val_pair = line.split(' ', 1)
        # if we do have a key seprated by a space
        if len(key_val_pair) > 1:
            key = key_val_pair[0]
            # proceed only if the key is enclosed within '<<' and '>>'
            if key.startswith('<<') and key.endswith('>>'):
                key = key[2:-2]
                # put more than one value in list, otherwise directly a string literal
                val = key_val_pair[1].split(',') if ',' in key_val_pair[1] else key_val_pair[1]

                my_dict[key] = val
    print my_dict
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finding_path(sys.argv[1])
```

Using a file like below

```
<<one>> 1, 5, 8
<<two>> hello
// this is a comment, it will be skipped
<<three>> 1,5,6
```

I get the output

```
{'three': ['1', '5', '6\n'], 'two': 'hello\n', 'one': ['1', ' 5', ' 8\n']}
```

Comment: Required output is {'three': [1,5,6], 'two': 'hello\n', 'one': [1, 5, 8]}

Comment: @DineshPundkar: your answer doesn't achieve that either.

Comment: Please, there is no need to call `f.readlines()`; you can iterate over the file object directly. Creating an empty dictionary is better done with `{}` (faster, as it uses an opcode rather than having to look up the built-in and call it). You probably want to pass in the file name into the function rather than use globals. And why call `f.close()` *twice*? You could use the file object as a context manager with the `with` statement and have the file closed automatically (even if there was an exception).

Comment: also file should be like <<something>> and your key need to be something

Comment: also my program sometimes got empty lines or comments, so I need to clear them. I can avoid in regex comments using if not re.match(r'^//', line):, but how to check in regex the line is empty?

Comment: @degath You mean empty lines/comments in the txt file? How are comments managed? How do they look like.

Comment: they are basic cpp comments so if on the begin line there is //  I know that I need to ignore this line so like I said I can use if not re.match(r'^//', line): do this function, but I need also do the job. but also need to maybe avoid empty lines or they wont be a problem in code?

Comment: @degath The current revision should naturally skip comments, as the line won't start with `<<`.

Comment: Well if they start with `//` then they will be skipped on failing to match with '<<'

Comment: Thanks for help guys. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code:

- Used regex to get key and value
- If the length of value list is 1, then converting it into string.

```
import re
demo_dict = {}

with open("val.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
          m= re.search(r"<<(.*?)>>(.*)",line)
          if m is not None:
               k = m.group(1)
               v = m.group(2).strip().split(',')
               if len(v) == 1:
                    v = v[0]
               demo_dict[k]=v
print demo_dict
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.Py
{'somethingelseelse': [' 1', '5', '6'], 'somethingelse': 'hello', 'something': [
'   1', ' 5', ' 8']}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @degath: you have lines that don't match the regular expression; the line could be empty for example. Skip lines where `m is None` is true.

Comment: Right, now the only thing left is skipping lines where the regex did not match.

Comment: Why not just use `if m is None:` in your previous revision? Now you do *two* regular expressions, where only one was needed.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to Dinesh's. I've added a function to convert the values in the list to numbers if possible, and some error handling so that if a line doesn't match, a useful warning is given.

```
import re
import warnings

regexp =re.compile(r'<<(\w+)>>\s+(.*)')

lines = ["<<something>>   1, 5, 8\n",
         "<<somethingelse>> hello\n",
         "<<somethingelseelse>> 1,5,6\n"]

#In real use use a file descriptor instead of the list
#lines = open('something.txt','r')

def get_value(obj):
    """Converts an object to a number if possible, 
    or a string if not possible"""
    try:
        return int(obj)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(obj)
    except ValueError:
        return str(obj)

dictionary = {}

for line in lines:    
    line = line.strip()
    m = re.search(regexp, line)
    if m is None:
        warnings.warn("Match failed on \n   {}".format(line))
        continue
    key = m.group(1)
    value = [get_value(x) for x in m.group(2).split(',')]
    if len(value) == 1: 
        value = value[0]
    dictionary[key] = value

print(dictionary)
```

output

```
{'something': [1, 5, 8], 'somethingelse': 'hello', 'somethingelseelse': [1, 5, 6]}
```